# jar file built by Eclipse cannot run on BlackBerry

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, jar

I built a project in Eclipse for my BlackBerry.

The jar cannot run on my BlackBerry. I get the error "907 Invaild JAR Descriptor missing required atrribute:MIDlet-1".

MANIFEST.MF from the Jar file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
RIM-MIDlet-Flags-1: 193
MIDlet-Vendor: <unknown>
MIDlet-Version: 1.0
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1
MIDlet-1: Co.Beginner,,
Created-By: 1.6.0_19 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
MIDlet-Jar-URL: contect.jar
MIDlet-Name: contect
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
MIDlet-Description: Get my contect
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a CLDC app in which case you don't need the JAR file for anything.  All you need are the JAD and COD files.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you actually wrote a [MIDlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDlet) (a.k.a a Java 2 ME application)?

A BlackBerry (and most other phones) can't simply run normal Java SE (a.k.a Desktop Java) applications, they need special applications. In the case of the BlackBerry those are eithe MIDlets or native BlackBerry applications developed with the [BlackBerry JDE](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/devtools.jsp).

You need to provide more information about your project so that we can find the problem.

Comment: I developed the project in eclipse with BlackBerry_JDE_PluginFull.

I can run the cod+jad file on my phone,but failed to run the jar file

Comment: MANIFEST.MF in the Jar is Manifest-Version: 1.0 RIM-MIDlet-Flags-1: 193 MIDlet-Vendor: <unknown> MIDlet-Version: 1.0 MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1 MIDlet-1: Co.Beginner,, Created-By: 1.6.0_19 (Sun Microsystems Inc.) MIDlet-Jar-URL: contect.jar MIDlet-Name: contect MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0 MIDlet-Description: Get my contect MIDlet-Jar-Size: 0

Comment: @Jeff: please edit your question to provide additional information. It's very hard to read in a comment.

Answer (score -1):

i was also facing this problem , but just .... i find a solution ..... sorry  i dont know too much about blackberry , but try this it will help you and i am using**strong text** **7.1** as my sdk !

open your blackberry emulator ---> File ( top left ) ---> load blackberry app ---> search the .cod file present in your ( project ---> deliverables ---> standard --->version number of sdk ( for me **7.1** ) ---> select .cod file .

after it i am pressing my menu button ( at left of the left_navigation_key ) and at there you will find that app !